# Why does input array change inside the recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand quick search algorithm in pyhton. Here is the code I am working on:

```
def partition2(a, l, r):
x = a[l]
j = l;
for i in range(l + 1, r + 1):
    if a[i] <= x:
        j += 1
        a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
a[l], a[j] = a[j], a[l]
return j



def randomized_quick_sort(a, l, r):

if l >= r:
    return
k = random.randint(l, r)
a[l], a[k] = a[k], a[l]
#use partition3
m = partition2(a, l, r)


randomized_quick_sort(a, l, m - 1);
randomized_quick_sort(a, m + 1, r);
```

Then I am calling this function defining a variable. For example:

```
b = [5,1,4]
randomized_quick_sort(b, 0, 2)
```

MY question is that when I try to print b after the function call, it prints as [1,4,5]. So, how come the value of this array is changing within the function??? It is not a global variable. Whey the local variables inside the function overrides it?? Please help

Comment: Lists aren't copied when they're passed into a function. It's one list between all recurses. If you change it, you "change it everywhere".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Quick question: so based on your answer, if it was a integer instead of a list, its value would not change??

Comment: Integers are immutable.

Comment: @prony It would not. It's for a different reason though. You can't alter a number because they're immutable. Numbers can never change. 1 will always be 1.You're seeing this behavior here because lists themselves are mutable; they can be changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have been trying to figure this out for a while!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you provide a list as a function argument you are passing a pointer to that list, meaning the parameter `a` isn't its own array, but a pointer to `b`.

What you are looking to do is provide only the items of the array `b` to `randomized_quick_sort()`

This can be done by making the following adjustment:

`randomized_quick_sort (b[:], 0, 2);`

Notice `b[:]` instead of `b`. Now, when you print `b` after calling the function you will have the same values as you did before.

You can find more information about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python)